# Why does EF fetch all records, then fetch all again by PK

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following EF6 fetch

```
       dgOrders.DataSource = Context.Orders
            .Where(o => o.ProposedOrder == ProposedOrders
                && o.Inactive == false
                && o.OnHold == false
                && o.Archive == false
                && (!o.ManufactureSiteFlag.HasValue || (o.ManufactureSiteFlag & currentSite) > 0)
                && (FilterOnDispatch == "" 
                    || (FilterOnDispatch.Equals("YES") && o.Deliveries.Count(d => d.Dispatched == true) > 0)
                    || (FilterOnDispatch.Equals("NO") && o.Deliveries.Count(d => d.Dispatched == false) > 0)));
```

When it executes it produces the following sequence of SQL on the server

```
(@p__linq__0 bit,@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__3 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__4 nvarchar(4000))
SELECT 
[Project3].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
[Project3].[OrderNum] AS [OrderNum], 
....
[Project3].[OrderDeliveryStatusID] AS [OrderDeliveryStatusID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project2].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    [Project2].[OrderNum] AS [OrderNum], 
    ....
    [Project2].[OrderDeliveryStatusID] AS [OrderDeliveryStatusID]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
        [Project1].[OrderNum] AS [OrderNum], 
        ....
        [Project1].[OrderDeliveryStatusID] AS [OrderDeliveryStatusID], 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Deliveries] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ([Project1].[OrderID] = [Extent3].[OrderID]) AND (0 = [Extent3].[Dispatched])) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
            [Extent1].[OrderNum] AS [OrderNum], 
            ....
            [Extent1].[OrderDeliveryStatusID] AS [OrderDeliveryStatusID], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Deliveries] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[OrderID] = [Extent2].[OrderID]) AND (1 = [Extent2].[Dispatched])) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    WHERE ([Project2].[ProposedOrder] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 = [Project2].[Inactive]) AND (0 = [Project2].[OnHold]) AND (0 = [Project2].[Archive]) AND (([Project2].[ManufactureSiteFlag] IS NULL) OR ((( CAST( [Project2].[ManufactureSiteFlag] AS int)) & (@p__linq__1)) > 0)) AND ((N'' = @p__linq__2) OR ((N'YES' = @p__linq__3) AND ([Project2].[C1] > 0)) OR ((N'NO' = @p__linq__4) AND ([Project2].[C2] > 0)))
)  AS [Project3]
```

and then produces

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
[Extent1].[OrderNum] AS [OrderNum], 
...
[Extent1].[OrderDeliveryStatusID] AS [OrderDeliveryStatusID]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1];

SELECT 
[Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
[Extent1].[OrderNum] AS [OrderNum], 
....
[Extent1].[OrderDeliveryStatusID] AS [OrderDeliveryStatusID]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[OrderID] IN (91,181,421,690,844,1544,2460,2682,2687,2736,2760,2806,2816,2817,2818,3134,3141,3154,3473,3726,4404,4583,4590,4641,4673,4677,4695,4737,4741,4789,4837,4885,4886,4887,4889,4993,5013,5018,5043,5046,5074,5090,5106,5134,5141,5231,5260,5261,5264,5265,5276,5369,5371,5421,5458,5513,5583,5688,5837,5863,5894,5895,5908,6002,6055,6084,6113,6128,6240,6432,6589,6590,6651,6676,6708,6733,6757,6772,6785,6831,6931,6934,6935,6936,7003,7004,7043,7068,7128,7135,7170,7172,7195,7223,7243,7325,7350,7360,7377,7452,7504,7508,7568,7613,7614,7641,7676,7714,7740,7764,7842,8008,8023,8174,8244,8250,8269,8312,8340,8346,8392,8437,8470,8488,8652,8664,8703,8710,8722,8750,8831,8920,9016,9181,9243,9262,9413,9421,9429,9621,9680,9707,9709,9710,9772,9787,9797,9832,9911,9918,9959,9961,9972,10042,10052,10056,10083,10120,10189,10221,10222,10253,10254,10293,10348,10413,10415,10430,10442,10452,10468,10491,10505,10529,10555,10573,10630,10662,10787,10791,10804,10838,10887,10933,10934,10955,10968,11010,11020,11059,11072,11078,11149,11151,11188,11281,11299,11421,11496,11502,11572,11647,11655,11758,11817,11948,12049,12082,12137,12201,12275,12406,12451,12466,12472,12516,12547,12581,12608,12650,12666,12720,12730,12732,12771,12775,12792,12807,12810,12843,12965,13074,13075,13085,13087,13102,13153,13198,13316,13326,13516,13763,13795,13800,13802,13867,13871,13878,13887,13891);
```

The second SQL statement is repeated multiple times with different primary key values.

Why is the first select statement not sufficient to satisfy the requirement of the request.  The subsequent set of statements appear to be returning a narrowed view of the dataset with no additional benefit.

Does it have something to do with the foreign key link to deliveries?

What can be done to improve performance here?

**UPDATE**: Apart from adopting some of the comments and answers below to improve performance on the original query, the additional fetches were tracked back to the *Context.Refresh* option which for some reason is the instigator of this behaviour.

Comment: I really don't see how the code you posted could generate that SQL, since nothing in your query tests OrderID, much less has a .Contains (which would be what the IN would be generated by).  FYI, .Any() will perform better than .Count() > 0 since .Count must count all records while Any uses EXISTS, which returns after finding the first record.

Comment: You are right - updated with correct first statement

Comment: Well, the first one is pretty standard for a complex query.  The multiple sub-selects are optimized away and nothing to worry about.  Again, the second set of queries I don't see how they could be related.  You would have to have a .Contains() method for the IN clause to get generated.  Are you sure it's not a secondary query?  Or are you adding additional expressions to the first query in later statements?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  It may be a byproduct of some columns in a DevExpress grid that is causing the generation.  I am still coming to grips with what is in the form code base.

Comment: I would bet it is...  The gird probably uses paging, which would create an IN clause to select a subset of records to view one page of data. it should be easy to find out... just comment out the grid, and perform a .ToList() on your query to execute it and see the actual query results.  It's probably also what's doing the unfiltered list, so that it can obtain a list of record id's and counts of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using parameters to turn parts of the query on or off, you should instead compose it instead of putting it inside the query itself. This should simplify the query itself.

```
var query = Context.Orders
        .Where(o => o.ProposedOrder == ProposedOrders
            && o.Inactive == false
            && o.OnHold == false
            && o.Archive == false
            && (!o.ManufactureSiteFlag.HasValue || (o.ManufactureSiteFlag & currentSite) > 0);

if (FilterOnDispatch.Equals("YES"))
    query = query.Where(o=>o.Deliveries.Count(d => d.Dispatched == true) > 0);
else if (FilterOnDispatch.Equals("NO"))
    query = query.Where(o=>o.Deliveries.Count(d => d.Dispatched == false) > 0);

dgOrders.DataSource = query;
```

Also, are you having any entities included in the query? Subsequent queries might be caused by EF having to pull related entities alongside the primary one.

Comment: Is there any way that I can get any subsequent queries, and the original source logged somewhere?

Comment: @sweetfa What do you mean? Those are same queries you see being executed on SQL server.

Comment: I want to trace the query back to the point in the original source.  Is there a flag that can be turned on to enable SQL logging related to an original source code command.  I can see what is happening on the server, but I cannot tell which particular piece of code is generating the SQL in the first place

Comment: @sweetfa - you might want to look into an EF profiler, either a stand-alone one or something like Glimpse.